# Putting "C#" in teams search breaks page

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, old-teams

If you put `C#` in the search box of Teams, the page breaks and looks like this

[image: C# search on Teams]

The top bar and the header is duplicated, and it doesn't look like it actually searches for `C#`.

Could this please be fixed?

Comment: I only briefly saw this- Mine flashed to being broken like this, then corrected itself. I am able to get that flash decently consistently, if I start from an empty search. I am unable to get it to stay, however.

Comment: Scratch that! Playing around with it more, I was able to reproduce perfectly. I had been hitting enter after typing my search, and that seems to force a refresh.

Comment: `#` anywhere in the search term reproduces this behavior.

Comment: Should be noted that you need to wait for the search to happen automatically for the error to come up. If you press enter search actually appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next push. The quick solution for search needed the final version with all of the sanity in place.